# Make JQ output a table

Tags: json, bash, jq, missing-data, tabular

My question is: how to make JQ output in a table format, replacing absent values with 0?

So the input for JQ is the following Elastic Search JSON response:

```
{"aggregations": {
    "overall": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z-2018-01-25T19:33:16.010Z",
                "from_as_string": "2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                "to": 1516908796010,
                "to_as_string": "2018-01-25T19:33:16.010Z",
                "doc_count": 155569,
                "agg_per_name": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "ASSET-DD583",
                            "doc_count": 3016,
                            "totalMaxUptime_perDays": {
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516579200000,
                                        "doc_count": 161,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 77598
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516665600000,
                                        "doc_count": 251,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 80789
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516752000000,
                                        "doc_count": 192,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 56885
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516838400000,
                                        "doc_count": 2088,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 7392705
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ASSET-DD568",
                            "doc_count": 2990,
                            "totalMaxUptime_perDays": {
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516233600000,
                                        "doc_count": 106,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 31241
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516320000000,
                                        "doc_count": 241,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 2952565
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516406400000,
                                        "doc_count": 326,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 2698235
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516492800000,
                                        "doc_count": 214,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 85436
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516579200000,
                                        "doc_count": 279,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 83201
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516665600000,
                                        "doc_count": 50,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 96467
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516752000000,
                                        "doc_count": 5,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 903
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516838400000,
                                        "doc_count": 1769,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 12337946
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ASSET-42631",
                            "doc_count": 2899,
                            "totalMaxUptime_perDays": {
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516233600000,
                                        "doc_count": 132,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 39054
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516320000000,
                                        "doc_count": 172,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 47634
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516406400000,
                                        "doc_count": 214,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 68264
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516492800000,
                                        "doc_count": 220,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 66243
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_as_string": "2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                                        "key": 1516838400000,
                                        "doc_count": 128,
                                        "totalMaxUptime": {
                                            "value": 47660
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

This JSON has some inherent properties:

1. There will be a variable number of buckets in agg_per_name.buckets
2. TotalMaxUptime_perDays.buckets represents a group by day for the last 7 days from the current date. The totalMaxUptime_perDays.buckets will have a number of buckets between 1 and 8 for every asset, each bucket corresponding to a certain date.

The desired output of JQ, for the given sample is a table where on horizontal you have the date from key_as_string (in this case from 18.01.2018 to 25.01.2018) and on vertical the all the asset keys (i.e. ASSET-DD583, ASSET-DD568, etc). The table is populated with totalMaxUptime.value for every corresponding date and if the date is not present in the result, a "0" value should be put instead:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX, 2018-01-18, 2018-01-19, 2018-01-20, 2018-01-21, 2018-01-22, 2018-01-23, 2018-01-24, 2018-01-25
ASSET-DD583, 0,           0,           0,         0,          77598,      80789,      56885,      7392705
ASSET-DD568, 31241,       2952565,     2698235,   85436,      83201,      96467,      903,        12337946
ASSET-42631, 39054,       47634,       68264,     66243,      0,          0,          0,          47660
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is how far I got:

```
input.json | jq '.aggregations.overall.buckets[0].agg_per_name.buckets[] | .key + ", " + (.totalMaxUptime_perDays.buckets[] | .key_as_string + ", " + (.totalMaxUptime.value | tostring))' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/T00:00:00.000Z//g'> uptime.csv
```

Which produces this kind of output:

```
ASSET-DD583, 2018-01-22, 77598
ASSET-DD583, 2018-01-23, 80789
ASSET-DD583, 2018-01-24, 56885
ASSET-DD583, 2018-01-25, 7392705
...............
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus sorry for that. Hope this helps. Basically my problem is that I don't know how to add 0 when data is missing for a specific date. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following, I've used `@tsv` so the output can more easily be seen as a table, but you might want to use `@csv`.

The tricky part here is to put the 0s in the right place.  Creating a JSON "dictionary" (i.e. JSON object) makes it easy. Here, `normalize` takes advantage of the fact that jq will honor the order in which keys are added to an object.

```
def dates:
  ["2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21", "2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25"];

def normalize:
  . as $in 
  | reduce dates[] as $k ({}; .[$k] = ($in[$k] // 0));

(["Asset"] + dates),
(.aggregations.overall.buckets[].agg_per_name.buckets[]
 | .key as $asset
 | .totalMaxUptime_perDays.buckets
 | map( { (.key_as_string | sub("T.*";"") ): .totalMaxUptime.value } ) 
 | add
 | normalize
 | [$asset] + [.[]]
 )
| @tsv
```

You might want to modify the above so that `dates` is computed from the data.

#### Output:

```
Asset   2018-01-18  2018-01-19  2018-01-20  2018-01-21  2018-01-22  2018-01-23  2018-01-24  2018-01-25
ASSET-DD583 0   0   0   0   77598   80789   56885   7392705
ASSET-DD568 31241   2952565 2698235 85436   83201   96467   903 12337946
ASSET-42631 39054   47634   68264   66243   0   0   0   47660
```

**EDIT:** Parentheses around `$in[$k] // 0` have been added.

Comment: You may use `@csv` or `join(",")` and then pipe the output from jq to `column -ts,`

Comment: Thanks @peak it works awesome!! One question: why does the "0" not show?

Comment: As CataTudorache noticed, a pair of parentheses was missing. (Thank you, @CataTudorache !)

Answer (score 5):

A partial solution for your problem.

You can put the values of an array on the same line if you use `@csv`.

For example, let's say you have

```
{
  "a": [1,2,3],
  "b": [
    {
      "x": 10
    },
    {
      "x": 20
    },
    {
      "x": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

To obtain `1,2,3` you should use `jq '.a | @csv'`

To obtain `10,20,30` you should use `jq '[.b[].x] | @csv'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
cat input.json
    | jq '.aggregations.overall.buckets[0].agg_per_name.buckets[] |
    .key + ", " + (.totalMaxUptime_perDays.buckets[] |
    .key_as_string + ", " + (.totalMaxUptime.value | tostring))' |column -t -s,
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be great if could add an explanation of the provided command that answers the question so that the asker of the question knows what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool to this.
https://github.com/uzimaru0000/tv

```
$ curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | tv
+--+------------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------+
|id|name                    |username        |email                    |address|phone                |website      |company|
+--+------------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------+
|1 |Leanne Graham           |Bret            |Sincere@april.biz        |...    |1-770-736-8031 x56442|hildegard.org|...    |
|2 |Ervin Howell            |Antonette       |Shanna@melissa.tv        |...    |010-692-6593 x09125  |anastasia.net|...    |
|3 |Clementine Bauch        |Samantha        |Nathan@yesenia.net       |...    |1-463-123-4447       |ramiro.info  |...    |
|4 |Patricia Lebsack        |Karianne        |Julianne.OConner@kory.org|...    |493-170-9623 x156    |kale.biz     |...    |
|5 |Chelsey Dietrich        |Kamren          |Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca |...    |(254)954-1289        |demarco.info |...    |
|6 |Mrs. Dennis Schulist    |Leopoldo_Corkery|Karley_Dach@jasper.info  |...    |1-477-935-8478 x6430 |ola.org      |...    |
|7 |Kurtis Weissnat         |Elwyn.Skiles    |Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz   |...    |210.067.6132         |elvis.io     |...    |
|8 |Nicholas Runolfsdottir V|Maxime_Nienow   |Sherwood@rosamond.me     |...    |586.493.6943 x140    |jacynthe.com |...    |
|9 |Glenna Reichert         |Delphine        |Chaim_McDermott@dana.io  |...    |(775)976-6794 x41206 |conrad.com   |...    |
|10|Clementina DuBuque      |Moriah.Stanton  |Rey.Padberg@karina.biz   |...    |024-648-3804         |ambrose.net  |...    |
+--+------------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------+
```